# What is the directory of the current workspace in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I used Eclipse to open a few external projecta and I am now wondering how to find out what the root directory of the current workspace is? I'm asking this question because in my scenario (using Eclipse to open external project), I think that the directory of the Eclipse workspace is different from the external project directories.

Comment: The header bar of the Eclipse window should show the name of the current project/file and workspace folder

Comment: @cricket_007, not for my case. :(

Comment: @cricket_007 It only shows part of the path

Comment: @EugeneSh. is correct. vote up. :)

Comment: In my case,  with Ubuntu 16 and Eclipse Oxygen, the header bar contains the workspace directory name  only when there are no files open to be edited. When files are open the full name and path of the current file are shown in the title bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
File -> Switch Workspace -> Other
```

And the selected folder will be workspace's one.

An alternative would be looking at Window's title (it has the workspace folder on it {at least on Mac OS X}).

Comment: @LinMa: You don't need to add a comment for every action (vote, accept, ...) that you do. The action itself is enough.

Answer (score 2):

It is

File->Switch Workspace->Other. Once you select other you get the current workspace.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows:
Create an "External tool" with following:
Location: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`
Arguments: `/C "echo ${workspace_loc}"`

Name it as you wish (like "Show workspace"). And you are done. Just run the "External tool" and the workspace path will be shown in Eclipse console.

Of course it can be easily done for Linux as well.